# Change DateTime format of property in object?

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime, object

I'm trying to change the date time format of "TimeStamp" which is a property in the object called "x"(for example).

```
public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
```

That is the property inside the object class.

How would I change it so it returns and sets the timestamp date time to the format of : dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DateTime` is an object type, while the format is just a representaion.
You could wrap it with a method, which performs a `DateTime.parse()` and `Timestamp.toString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")`.